# Unable to launch java

Tags: java, windows, jvm

When I try to do java from commands prompt in windows I am getting this error :

> Error loading: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll

The dll is there and it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try load Filemon.exe (sysinternal utility from Microsoft site) - when you start, it can create report what exactly failed when loading DLLs. My assumption that your local java miss some DLL or has mistake in the PATH variable. Filemon.exe usually helps to detect it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Java default installation has been corrupted in one way or another.

I would suggest uninstalling and go to http://java.com/en/ to get the browser to auto-detect and install the correct files for your system.